# Changing RStudio package library location

Tags: r, rstudio

After I formatted my PC a few days back, I reinstalled R (3.4.1) and RStudio (1.0.153). Previously the default location for installing packages was inside the "Documents" inside my user folder. But after I reinstalled the RStudio, the default folder has shifted to inside the "OneDrive" folder. How do I shift the package library to other location?